# DigiKam: Exclude raw files in slideshow

Tags: digikam

In my folders I store images as raw and as jpg as I'm not comfortable with a pure raw photography workflow yet. I regularly group the files by filename when applying operations such as rating or face tagging, which works pretty well.

The only thing which does not work well is having a slideshow  (*full screen view*) for the JPEG's only.

How can I avoid seeing raw + jpg in the slideshow and only get the JPEG's?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to not have both images in the same directory - I separate my raws from my jpegs in two different directory hierarchies, which are identical, except for a different parent directory (i.e. they're organized the same, but in different places). That way, I point digikam at the jpeg hierarchy, and darktable/rawtherapee at the raw hierarchy...

Comment: @twalberg yeah, I'm starting to thinking about such a change or some general improvement of my workflow. I still have to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of an "X-Y problem" in the headline question - as far as I know it's a bit of a pain to exclude a certain type of image.

Fortunately, it's very easy to set up a slideshow with only the pictures you want to see, particularly when this is a type of file (for example only .jpg).

Change the display to the "Table" format (assuming it wasn't on that already - Digikam usually defaults to thumbnails). Click at the top of the column to sort by "Type". Click on the first .jpg, then shift-click on the last to block select.

[If you want to get fancy, CTRL-click lets you select and deselect any files you want - this approach also works from the thumbnail display, and could be used after "Select all" to exclude specific files if you really wanted to do it that way.]

At the right of the "Slideshow" tab there should be a drop-down menu. Check this is on "Selection" (and not "All").

Press the "Slideshow" button (or ALT-F9) to run the slideshow of the selected files.

Comment: Thanks. This works but I'd hoped for something easier with less clicks. Sounds like there is room for some improvement, either on my end (separate raw+jpg?) or on the digiKam side.